# Why timer control makes the application very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

The program in windows form application is working well until i use timer control where i choose the interval of it (1 ms) to get 1000 values, visually i should get these 1000 values in a period of one second but i get them in a period of about 14 seconds it's very slow.
Does anyone know why and how to solve this?

Comment: Do you think your computer can handle "get 1000 values" per millisecond? That sounds like an awful lot to do in very little time.

Comment: A timer doesn't tick at 1 msec intervals.  The minimum is 15.6 msec on most machines.  Close enough to x14 to call it.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not 1000 values per millisecond. it's 1 value in millisecond thus 1000 values per second. and I think it can do it because in some applications like matlab, LabView, and Proteus that can happen.